# Is there any way to get available resolutions for a vimeo/youtube video over their api endpoints?

Tags: php, youtube-data-api, vimeo-api, youtube-dl

I want to check for the available resolutions over the api call when I am retrieving the video details against their video ids (e.g - Im69kzhpR3I[youtube] or 64765355[vimeo]). See My Application searches videos against a keyword. I am using youtube Data API's [`search/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint & vimeo's [`videos`](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos) endpoint. I want to get the available resolutions during these calls if possible.

I am using [Youtube-Dl](https://github.com/norkunas/youtube-dl-php) library with [Youtube-Dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) working on back. I could use the youtube-Dl directly on shell. But this library was pretty convenient. What my problem is that the library disabled the `--list-formats` parameter so can't check before downloading using youtube-dl. so I want to fetch the available options prior & then pick one which I will provide to the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Update:

Well My patience outran.. ended up fetching the best possible mp4 based format through the `--list-formats` through `exec()`.